# PHP error: A non-numeric value encountered in file.php on line 180 in file_exists function

Tags: php

I am getting this error in php that says

```
A non-numeric value encountered in file.php on line 180
```

Here is my code

```
$path = $pth + '/logo.png';
if(file_exists($path)){
    echo 'yes';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

I also got this error with other file operations also like `copy()` and `mkdir()`. Removing `.` and `/` makes them work fine.

Any way to solve this error. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is `$pth`?

Comment: its the path of the file. I have defined that

Comment: `+` is not concatenating. `.` is concatenating, this is __not javascript__.

Comment: why so it is not concatenating

Comment: Because it is not javascript, it is __php__.

Comment: You are free to downvote my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. [Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
$path = $pth.'/logo.png';
if(file_exists($path)){
    echo 'yes';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: I knew that. Seems like should stop python for some days

Comment: I use PHP and JavaScript for my project, sometimes I have the same problem. We all make mistakes. you can solve your problem as soon as possible by practicing.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$path = $pth . '/logo.png';
if(file_exists($path)){
 echo 'yes';
}
 else{
  echo 'no';
}
```